# potency in preformed germ-line

Tags: stem-cells

In organism that have a preformed germ-line like Drosophila where germ cells are pre-allocated in the oocyte, are there technically no adult pluripotent stem cells since germ line cells can't be developed from somatic stem cells?

Answer (score 3):

In almost all metazoa, the pro-germline cells get segregated from other stem cells at an early stage of development and they thrive and differentiate in their neighborhood. This is important in order to preserve the germline. This [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/how-are-new-people-created-from-the-dna-of-an-aged-person-i-e-why-are-we-young/8017#8017) provides some basic explanation.

However, even drosophila have adult multipotent stem cells and help in the formation of midgut as reported by [this](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v439/n7075/abs/nature04333.html) study.